# Difference between JS onclick and jQuery .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I try two different ways to call the onclick function.
Like this :

```
<input type="button" value="G" id="gras"></input>
<input type="button" value="I" onclick="insertTag('&lt;italique&gt;', '&lt;/italique&gt;', 'textarea')" />
```

and like this :

```
$("#gras").on("click", function() {
insertTag("&lt;gras&gt;", "&lt;/gras&gt;", "textarea"); });
```

Only the first one is working.
Here is my regexp :

```
field = field.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
field = field.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
field = field.replace(/\n/g, '<br />').replace(/\t/g, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');

field = field.replace(/&lt;gras&gt;([\s\S]*?)&lt;\/gras&gt;/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
field = field.replace(/&lt;italique&gt;([\s\S]*?)&lt;\/italique&gt;/g, '<em>$1</em>');
```

Thanks!

Comment: The DOM is probably not ready. Wrap your `on()` method in a `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: That's ok, but not still working :/

Comment: Provide the code you have used in the question.

Answer (score -2):

Here is JS :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#gras").on("click", function() {
  insertTag("&lt;gras&gt;, &lt;/gras&gt;, textarea");
 });
});
function insertTag(startTag, endTag, textareaId, tagType) {
 var field = document.getElementById(textareaId);
 var scroll = field.scrollTop;
 field.focus();
 var startSelection   = field.value.substring(0, field.selectionStart);
 var currentSelection = field.value.substring(field.selectionStart, field.selectionEnd);
 var endSelection     = field.value.substring(field.selectionEnd);
 field.value = startSelection + startTag + currentSelection + endTag + endSelection;
 field.focus();
 field.setSelectionRange(startSelection.length + startTag.length, startSelection.length + startTag.length + currentSelection.length);
}   

function preview(textareaId) {
 var field = textareaId.value;
 field = field.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
 field = field.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
 field = field.replace(/\n/g, '<br />').replace(/\t/g, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'); 
 field = field.replace(/&lt;gras&gt;([\s\S]*?)&lt;\/gras&gt;/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
 field = field.replace(/&lt;italique&gt;([\s\S]*?)&lt;\/italique&gt;/g, '<em>$1</em>');
 document.getElementById("previewDiv").innerHTML = field;
 console.log(field);
}

var area = document.getElementById("textarea");
preview(area);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<title>WYSIWYG</title>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
 <div>
  <p>
   <input type="button" value="G" id="gras"></input>
   <input type="button" value="I" onclick="insertTag('&lt;italique&gt;', '&lt;/italique&gt;', 'textarea')" />
  </p> 
 </div> 
 <textarea id="textarea" cols="150" rows="10"></textarea>
 <div id="previewDiv"></div>
</div>
<script src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="wysiwyg.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't provide extra information to your **question** in an **answer**... You may freely edit your post anytime.

Comment: delete this answer, and add this information in your question.
You are calling insertTag with only 1 variable:  
"&lt;gras&gt;, &lt;/gras&gt;, textarea".
that's rare, because your first pasted code showed other thing...